# Why would a C# .NET WinForms app's controls display differently on a different machine? Black-box testing approaches

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, testing

I am "blackbox" testing a C# .NET Windows Forms application (blackbox testing: testing without source code and perhaps also without knowledge of the software's development patterns). I have two Win7 64-bit machines that /should/ provide identical environments for testing (they both have the same versions of .NET installed, same software versions, same network, etc.).

I've discovered a bug/inconsistency on one of the application's forms. It always occurs (and has since first installing the application) on one of the two machines, but never occurs on the other. It's a control layout issue: a couple of text boxes are out of place (partially off the screen). None of the application's windows are re-sizable, and both machines have the same screen resolution and display methods. The issue has always existed on the machine where it exists, and my testing methods on both machines are (as far as I know) equivalent.

While I'm curious to know what an experienced C# .NET WinForms developer might think to address first, I'm more interested in how to approach such an issue from a testing perspective, in as abstract logic as possible. What kinds of assumptions might be effective for making efficient progress in testing such an issue? What kinds of software environment questions might be appropriate to ask? Is there any way of approaching such problems that can--without specific knowledge of my software or environment--increase the likelihood of finding why something like this might happen?

Again, this question is about *testing* and appropriate answers will *not* include responses like "Look at the source code", "Ask the developer", etc. because there may be cases when this type of blackbox testing is the /only/ approach available for testing certain software. I cannot provide any screenshots or detailed information about the software- only general descriptions, but please ask for clarification and I'll do my best to provide it.

Comment: DPI settings come to mind. Also verify that the program are exactly the same, (compare SHA1 hashes or something).

Comment: Different video cards and drivers can sometimes cause different behaviors.

Comment: Thanks @vcsjones for suggesting DPI - that was the issue. I'm still eager to hear more ideas about testing approaches in this case. If you post an actual answer, I'll give you a +1.

Comment: @mdscruggs Glad that fixed it, though I feel like I am not really answering your question, just a byproduct of it. I'd be interested in what answers you get, too.

Comment: As for testing, the way to test these factors is to hire a human QA engineer. I'm not trying to be facetious. From experience, testing non-trivial UI layouts with automated methods will cost more (in money and pain) than having a dedicated QA person (or a programmer who dedicates some time to QA).

Comment: I don't really get the testing need.  You look at it and say "that's wrong!" and send it back to the dev.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't given that they are in fact the exact same setup but here are a few things to consider as possible differences between the two.

- Aero settings
- Resolution/DPI
- Default Font Size/Face (if these are changed by a theme for instance they can change the widths of pieces of text)
- Using different version of the application on the two machines.

Answer (score 0):

I would double check all your personal settings are the same on both computer:

- Icon sizes
- font sizes
- resolution

I have also ran into this when one monitor was Standard and the other was Widescreen formats.

Answer (score 0):

Look at AutoScaleMode. Should be set to None